# Levenshtein distance in ROOM database

Tags: android, android-room

I have created an application that using some predefined dictionaries (for different languages) to show user matching word (each word atm is search by normalised value e.g. "łowić" -> "lowic" and search by given prefix). The problem is it is not very useful as it is usual that user will mistype some characters and using this solution, i am not able to show him proper hint. As it was available in SQLite to add extensions, that in ROOM database i can not find any way to do it. The extra problem here is that the dictionaries can contain enormous number of words so i can not calculate this by my own.

So:

- is there any way to use extensions like https://github.com/agusibrahim/android-sqlite-extension in room database?
- if not, should i use other database or can i do it other way?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tried it my guess is no, you cannot use Room with [Android SQLite support library](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android#android-sqlite-support-library).
The reason is that Room depends on the SQLite3 built-in packages and doesn't "know" that this library exists in your project.

You can skip using Room and include that package in your project and then use the extension as explained in the base project:
 [Android SQLite support library](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android#android-sqlite-support-library)

and the extensions project:
[SQLite3 Extension for Android](https://github.com/agusibrahim/android-sqlite-extension#sqlite3-extension-for-android)